# How to switch to an Activity that is running through an already running Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I know there are much discussions about this but i cannot get this to work properly.

`Activity` (A) = `singleTop` and can receive `android.intent.action.SEND`
`Activity` (B) = `singleTask`

When i from the Android Gallery select a picture and open it with (A)
The (A) is redirecting the intent to (B).

This is working ok and if i press HOME and select (A) from the luncher
the (B) is brought to front. That is what i want and user can continue with picture,

Now, if i press HOME and open the Android Gallery again the (A) is
`onRestart()`, `OnStart()` and `onResume()`. and i see (A).

This is the problem i like to switch to (B) because user need to finish what he was doing.

I cannot see a good way to do that and why does the Android Gallery resume (A)?
Maybe i do something wrong since opening the Android Gallery bring me (A)
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can tell what are you trying to do minus the technical terms. i got confused

Comment: @Harsha I dont understand what you talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE
I know this is an intricate scenario. I have made a working solution by simply  killing (A)/finish() after the launch of (B). Now,

if i press HOME and open the Android Gallery again i see Android Gallery.
if i press HOME and open A i see B.
if i press back from B I see the gallery

Answer (score 0):

This is possible reasoning based on limited info in the question, assuming A is redirecting the intent to B in its onCreate().

1) Open Gallery, select a picture, open with A, redirect it to B

```
Task1 has stack has Gallery, A, B (B on top of the stack)
```

2) Press home, select A from launcher

```
Launcher app creates a new task, new task2's stack has a new instance of activity A, its onCreate() is invoked and intent is redirected to B. B being a singleTask is moved from Task1 to Task2 and its onNewIntent() would be invoked.
```

3) Press home, and open gallery

```
Task1 is resumed and the top of the stack is now A. Its onRestart(), onStart() and onResume() is invoked.
```

This being the scenario, you can try redirecting the intent from A's onStart() or do not have B as singleTask.

Comment: Your absolutely right i think, this is my assumption to about what's going on, (2)The onNewIntent() is firing as you say. Now when we know what the question is and we have an answer - "redirecting the intent from A's onStart()". How do i do that, is there some reliable way to find out if B is running, because i dont want to start B if it not running. If you know can you update your answer

Comment: Well, i assumed B is always started when you mentioned " redirecting intent to B" and that its being done in onCreate() of A, which is why i suggested to move it to A's onStart(). If the assumption isn't correct, please clarify and post the code "of redirecting intent"

Comment: Thanks. I know this is an intricate scenario. I have made a working solution by simply  killing (A)/finish() after the launch of (B)   Now, if i press HOME and open the Android Gallery again the New (A) brought into (B) stack.

Comment: What about case when you press back from B. Wouldn't it go directly to Gallery rather than A?